# Screen Doesn't Revert to Original when Changed Once

Tags: javascript, css, angular

HTML Template

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="listItem.imagePosition==='left'&&viewIsMobile==false; then thenBlock; "></div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="listItem.imagePosition==='right'&&viewIsMobile==false; then elseBlock; "></div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="innerWidth <=500; then mobileBlock; "></div>


<ng-template #thenBlock >

   //content

</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseBlock >

    //content
</ng-template>


<ng-template #mobileBlock>

   // content
</ng-template>
```

Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 

  public innerWidth : any ;
  viewIsMobile:boolean = false;

  constructor() {
   
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if(this.innerWidth<=500){
    this.viewIsMobile = true;
  }

}

}
```

The problem I'm facing is when I resize to Mobile and go back I will Not get the content of thenBlock and elseBlock. I have being trying to find the cause for this but still couldn't. The main problem here is that when the screen resizes it will not change the boolean value to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="listItem.imagePosition==='left'&&innerWidth>500 ; then thenBlock; "></div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="listItem.imagePosition==='right'&&innerWidth>500 ; then elseBlock; "></div>

  onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
```